# Compare files within two folder using python

Tags: python

I have two folders "Old_2014" and "New_2015" both folder has files such as

```
Old_2014=abl_results 
         abc_results1
New_2015=abl_results
         abcd_results1
```

old_2014/abl_results-> has 21 items
new_2014/abl_results-> has 165 items

I want to compare these files and copy the Unique records in new folder
similarly i have total 103 files name abc, abcd,abcde etc.
eg:- I need to find the files which are there in the old but not in the new
and at the end the, the results file need to have the unique value

Comment: Diff will just compare, I need to know if any files has been added or removed?

Comment: Like both the files has same name, so let say if there is any new file, that also i want to keep

Comment: Note: your question is attracting close-votes for being too broad.   Since you're a new user, you might want to check out the "how to ask a good question" [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and note that you are expected to post your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that does what you asked for:

```
import os

old_dir = "old_d"
new_dir = "new_d"

files_old = os.listdir(old_dir)
files_new = os.listdir(new_dir)

print "In old not in new:", list(set(files_old) - set(files_new))
```

Specifically: it lists files that are in the old that are not in the new.

```
~ mgregory$ mkdir old_d
~ mgregory$ mkdir new_d
~ mgregory$ touch old_d/1.txt
~ mgregory$ touch old_d/2.txt
~ mgregory$ touch new_d/1.txt
~ mgregory$ python foo.py
In old not in new: ['2.txt']
~ mgregory$
```

Things to note:

- You can get the list of files in a directory as a list using `listdir()`
- You can do interesting set operations with lists by converting them to sets
- If you wanted to know what is in new that is not in old, you should look up [the doco on sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

---

Another note: enrico's answer is also correct:

```
~ mgregory$ diff old_d new_d
Only in old_d: 2.txt
~ mgregory$
```

diff does a good job of diffing directories.

Comment: Inside old= abc_reulsts there are xml's eg:-  1.xml, 2.xml, 3.xml  new = 5.xml   so the output should be 5.xml

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  This is the first time you've mentioned xml files. Please see the advice for asking good questions, and follow it.

Comment: I am just asking i have a folder name old_2014 which has a file abc_results inside abc_results i have some xml files, on the other hand new_2015 also has the abc_results and it has some xml files so now i want to compare these two xml

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question :)

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question.   Otherwise you render the answers given previously  as useless, which is not a good thing.